# Mac: create group for use with mobile & local accounts

Tags: mac, homebrew, osx-server

I need to create a group that will contain the local admin of a machine *and* one or more Network (Mobile account) users (from a Mountain Lion Server).

I'm wondering where to create the group `brewers` (for **homebrew**. I need a few users to be able to `brew` but I don't want to add the network users to the already existing `admin` group).

I could create the group:

- in the `Users & Group` System Preference or…
- in `Server.app` on the server.

Is there a preference? Is there a functional difference? The group will have users from both a local account *and* the networked account.